# Docx4j convert html to docx

Tags: java, docx4j

I have new problem when I convert HTML to docx it throws exception:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 4; columnNumber: 73; The entity "nbsp" was referenced, but not declared

As I understood, it is because docx4j thinks that my file is XML and wants to convert it to docx but there are only 5 predefined entities in XML and such entities as nbsp are not defined in XML. How can I make docx4j convert HTML to doc, without declaring the entity nbsp in the doctype?

Is it incorrect work of docx4j or it's limitation?

Here is my code:

```
package ru.simplexsoftware.constructorOfDocuments.web.rest;
import org.docx4j.convert.in.xhtml.XHTMLImporterImpl;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.NumberingDefinitionsPart;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.HttpRequestHandler;
import ru.simplexsoftware.constructorOfDocuments.dao.TemplateDao;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;


public class DocxFileDownloadServlet implements HttpRequestHandler {

@Autowired
TemplateDao templateDao;
@Override
public void handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String parameter = request.getParameter("documentId");

    Long documentId = Long.parseLong(parameter);

    WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = null;
    try {
        wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();
    } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    NumberingDefinitionsPart ndp = null;
    try {
        ndp = new NumberingDefinitionsPart();
    } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addTargetPart(ndp);
    } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        ndp.unmarshalDefaultNumbering();
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    XHTMLImporterImpl xHTMLImporter = new XHTMLImporterImpl(wordMLPackage);
    xHTMLImporter.setHyperlinkStyle("Hyperlink");

    String htmlString=templateDao.get(documentId).html;
    htmlString = htmlString.replaceAll("<br>","<br/>");
    InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()));
    // Convert the XHTML, and add it into the empty docx we made
    try {
        wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getContent().addAll(
                xHTMLImporter.convert(htmlString, null));
    } catch (Docx4JException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try {
        wordMLPackage.save(outputStream);
    } catch (Docx4JException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    response.setContentType("application/msword");
    response.getOutputStream().write(outputStream.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
    response.flushBuffer();

}
}
```

Comment: Declare the entity manually or pre-process through a tidy program.  docx4j-ImportXHTML expects well formed XML input.

Comment: JasonPlutext is it possible to declare all entities by some method? I just don't want declare all html entities manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use **AltChunkType** type to insert HTML string into docx paragraph

```
wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addAltChunk(AltChunkType.Xhtml, htmlString .getBytes());
```